# Groovy writing single method insted of two each function

Tags: groovy

I am a Groovy beginner

These are two `each` calls which both do a similar task but with a different property of `s2PublicLifecycleInstance`.

How can I write a separate function which does the following, so that I can have only method call to achive the task?

```
def scheduledStatusArray =[]
def publishedStatusArray =[]

s2PublicLifecycleInstance.each {
  if(it.scheduledInMyLearnStatus == "No"){
    scheduledStatusArray.add(1)
  } else if(it.scheduledInMyLearnStatus == "Yes"){
    scheduledStatusArray.add(2)
  }else{
    scheduledStatusArray.add(3)
  }
}

s2PublicLifecycleInstance.each {
  if(it.publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus == "No"){
    publishedStatusArray.add(1)
  }else if(it.publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus == "Yes"){
    publishedStatusArray.add(2)
  }else{
    publishedStatusArray.add(3)
  }
}
```

I want something like this:

```
def publishedStatusArray = functionCall(s2PublicLifecycleInstance, propertyName)
```

is it possible in Groovy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with gasan. I can add, that 
`def publishedStatusArray = functionCall(s2PublicLifecycleInstance, propertyName)`
is possible in groovy. The function:

> `functionCall(def s2PublicLifecycleInstance, String propertyName){
>   s2PublicLifecycleInstance."$propertyName"
>   }`

will return the property you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could use closures and currying:

```
def checkStatus = { prop,instances ->
   def statuses = instances.collect {
      switch( it[prop] ) {
      case "Yes": 1
         break
      case "No": 2
         break
      default: 3
      }
   }
   return statuses
}

def checkScheduledStatus = checkStatus.curry("scheduledInMyLearnStatus")
def checkPublishedStatus = checkStatus.curry("publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus")

def scheduledStatusArray = checkScheduledStatus(s2PublicLifecycleInstance)
def publishedStatusArray = checkPublishedStatus(s2PublicLifecycleInstance)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def myMethod(param, arrayToAdd) {
  if(param == "No"){
                arrayToAdd.add(1)
            }else if(param == "Yes"){
                arrayToAdd.add(2)
            }else{
                arrayToAdd.add(3)
            }
}


s2PublicLifecycleInstance.each {myMethod(it.scheduledInMyLearnStatus, scheduledStatusArray)}

s2PublicLifecycleInstance.each {myMethod(it.publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus, publishedStatusArray)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way using a method:

```
List check( List lifecycle, String param ) {
  lifecycle.collect { it ->
    switch( it."$param" ) {
      case "No":
        return 1
      case "Yes":
        return 2
      default:
        return 3
    }
  }
}

def scheduledStatusArray = check( s2PublicLifecycleInstance, 'scheduledInMyLearnStatus' )
def publishedStatusArray = check( s2PublicLifecycleInstance, 'publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus' )
```

Or, you could do this (which is less code):

```
List check( List lifecycle, String param ) {
  def retvals = [ 'No':1, 'Yes':2 ].withDefault { 3 }
  lifecycle.collect { it ->
    retvals[ it."$param" ]
  }
}
```

Another alternative would be to use inject with multiple assignment:

```
def (scheduledStatusArray, publishedStatusArray) = s2PublicLifecycleInstance.inject( [[],[]] ) { lists, it ->
  lists[ 0 ] << ( it.scheduledInMyLearnStatus == 'No' ? 1 :
                  it.scheduledInMyLearnStatus == 'Yes' ? 2 : 3 )
  lists[ 1 ] << ( it.publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus == 'No' ? 1 :
                  it.publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus == 'Yes' ? 2 : 3 )
  lists
}
```